# Kindly guide with upgrading kaa 0.9.0 to latest 0.10.0

Tags: kaa

Please guide me with instruction on upgrading kaa 0.9.0 to 0.10.0 which is the release update as per date as I can't see any information under this link to upgrade http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/Upgrading-your-instance/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upgrade Kaa from 0.9.0 to latest 0.10.0 version look at [this](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Administration-guide/Upgrading-your-instance/0.9.x-to-0.10.x/) guide.